# xamarin android webview no longer retrieves page served locally with httplistener

Tags: android, webview, xamarin

We have a xamarin android app that contains a httplistener that serves up html, js, css and json calls, to a single page app running in a full screen webview. As of Xamarin 3.5 onwards the webview fails to retrieve this localhost address which we run on port 31316. Prior to this release this was functioning correctly.

From what i can see, the httplistener seems healthy, as we can call it with the WebRequest library correctly, which leads me tb believe that something has changed to the webview.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a sample app demonstrating the behaviour:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace HttpListenerTest
{
    [Activity (Label = "HttpListenerTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(HttpListenerTestService)));

        var webView = (WebView)this.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        webView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
        webView.Settings.BlockNetworkLoads = false;
        webView.LoadUrl("http://localhost:31316/");
        //webView.LoadData (Activities.html, "text/html", "UTF-8");

        var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert1;
            alert1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            try
            {

                if(!Activities.httpListener.IsListening)
                {
                    alert1.SetMessage("Listener has stopped listening");
                    alert1.Show();
                    return;
                }

                string url = "http://localhost:31316/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("O");

                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));                 
                request.Method = "GET";

                string responseString = "";

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                    responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    response.Close();
                    reader.Close();
                }

                alert1.SetMessage(responseString);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                alert1.SetMessage(e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace);
            }

            alert1.Show();
        };
    }
}

[Service(Label = "HttpListenerTest Service")]
public class HttpListenerTestService : Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        Activities.InitRest();
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {

    }

    public override void OnStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        base.OnStart(intent, startId);
    }

    private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public static class Activities
{
    public static HttpListener httpListener { get; set; }

    public static Thread RestThread { get; set; }

    public const string html = "<html>hello world</html>";

    public static void InitRest()
    {
        RestThread = new Thread(StartRest) { Name = "Rest Service" };
        RestThread.Start();
    }

    private static void StartRest()
    {
        httpListener = new HttpListener { IgnoreWriteExceptions = true };
        httpListener.Prefixes.Add(@"http://localhost:31316/");
        httpListener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
        httpListener.Start();
        httpListener.BeginGetContext(HandleRequest, httpListener);
    }

    public static void HandleRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("==========================HandleRequest==========================");
        var context = httpListener.EndGetContext(result);
        var unescapedUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(context.Request.RawUrl);


        var bytes = new byte[html.Length * sizeof(char)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(html.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        context.Response.ContentLength64 = bytes.Length;
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        //context.Response.ContentEncoding = "UTF-8";
        context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
        context.Response.OutputStream.Dispose();
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        httpListener.BeginGetContext(HandleRequest, httpListener);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What Android version are you testing on? What kind of device are you testing on?

Comment: The Nexus 7 Jelly Bean on Xamarin Android Player, ASUS Transformer Pad TF300T and Galaxy Not 10.1 (2013)

Comment: Changing over to "file:///android_asset/ for serving out the files has fixed our problem and our HttpListener can still serve out our rest web services. It would be good to know why Xamarin blocked this feature though.